# How to keep existing button style when applying background image?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to add a background image to a button. I have a simple input button that I'm using as a toggle for displaying a div. I want to put an image in the button. I'm using the following HTML.

```
<input type='button' id='toggleButton'>
```

When I view this in my web page in Firefox 9.0.1 it looks great: [image: Fancy button image]

I applied the following style to it to add my image:

```
#toggleButton {
    background-image: url("plus.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

As soon as I apply the background image the button becomes very plain: [image: Plain button image]

I used Firebug to examine the computed style of both buttons and it didn't show any difference other than the style I appled and some minor changes in border width (from 2.5px to 1.66667px). I added `border-width: 2.5px;` to the style and it didn't help.

My image has an alpha channel and only the black of the plus sign should show. My understanding of CSS is that the original button's style should still be applied and my button only adds the background image. I expected to end up with a button that looks approximately like this: [image: Button that I want]

How do I add the background image and keep the fancy button look?

Answer (score 1):

How about try something like this if you just want to add a plus symbol:

Html:

```
<input type='button' id='toggleButton' value="+" />
```

CSS:

```
#toggleButton {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #444444;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried and rejected that solution because the minus sign doesn't match up with the plus sign on toggle. The bar of the minus sign isn't wide enough and it displays several pixels below the plus sign. In any case, your answer doesn't address the question of how to apply a background image and have the button continue to inherit the default style. I may want to reuse this solution in the future with different images that can't be represented in a character set.

Answer (score 0):

Please try making your button picture to circular bead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer at all.

Comment: Seems there are two way to make button looks good at least. one is use CSS style to control it. another is change button's background image. so i suggest him using the second one. Trying make background image better. Using PS or Indesign...

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to replace the button with an image. I want to composite an image into the background of the button that the browser provides and do so with the button continuing to inherit its default style.