# Why does adding a background image to an input (button) change it's default browser user agent styling?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/eJSGn/

```
input{
    padding-left: 20px;        
}

input:last-of-type{
    background: url(http://skiorboard.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/search.png) no-repeat;    
    background-size:15px 15px;
}

<input type="button" value=" Search " />
<input type="button" value=" Search " />
<input type="button" value=" Search " />
```

So if I have three input buttons and style the last of the three to have a background image (magnifying glass) why does the adding of this image to the third button also result in drastic changes to the button?  In chrome, for example, the third button's background turns white and the border style changes.

I want to use the browser's default styles for these buttons, but would like to be able to add a background image to the button without it making that button look totally different than the other buttons which I will not be adding icons to.

Comment: I have downvoted no one so far (and rarely ever downvote in my own posts).  I understand that the user agent (e.g. Chrome, Firefox) has its own set of CSS styles for each input element.  This is why a button looks slightly different in Chrome than it does in Firefox.  What I don't understand is why changing ONE part of the input's style (i.e. adding a small background image) will result in AUTOMATIC changes to other parts of the style (i.e. border, background-color).  This just doesn't make sense to me and I want all of my buttons to look the same (except for this one which will have an icon).

Comment: That's not entirely correct, let me try to rephrase – the default button style is usually not created using CSS, therefore when you change a visual aspect of it (e.g. border) it shifts to a default CSS version of the button. You can change things like width and height without switching the default look, but the native button hasn't got a CSS background, border etc.. That's why it changes. Do you get it now?

Comment: I was basically writing up this same question.  Sad to see there's no good answer for it.  Another one with no good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091118/how-to-keep-existing-button-style-when-applying-background-image

Answer (score 0):

Your overriding the background property which browsers use to set their defaults (browser set styles have the very lowest [CSS priority](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)). It would be the same as doing.

```
/* This will override browser styles. */
button
{
  background: grey;
}

/* This will override the above style */
button
{
  background: black;
}

/* This will override the above style */
button
{
  background: blue!important;
}
```

Each one has more priority over the other therefore overriding it.

Comment: Just adding a background image and sizing that image shouldn't affect the input button's border, though, should it?  The part that is confusing me is that I just add a single image to the button and everything else changes too (e.g. background color, border style).

Comment: I don't think this is the answer he was looking for, he's asking about why the "look" changes, which I've explained below (but got downvoted for some reason!)